# Java OutOfMemory error with OrientDB cluster mode

Tags: jvm, orientdb, graph-databases, distributed

I am trying to connect to read a large table (5,000,000 rows) from the OrientDB database with select and native API driver. When I connect to the local database, the applications loads for some time and then such a message is displayed:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Here are the parameters I defined for JVM in order to improve performance. Without these parameters I get `GC overhead limit` error:

```
-Xmx800m -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=7200 -server -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem
```

What should I change in this settings or in the cluster settings in order to fix thsi error and to run the application?

OrientDB is set up in a clustered mode using Docker:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node1:
    image: orientdb:latest
    command: /orientdb/bin/server.sh -Ddistributed=true
    volumes:
      - /orientdb/config1:/opt/orientdb/config
      - /orientdb/databases1:/orientdb/databases
      - /orientdb/backup1:/orientdb/backup
      - ./data:/orientdb/bin/data
    environment:
      ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pwd1'
      ORIENTDB_NODE_NAME: node1
    ports:
      - "2424:2424"
      - "2480:2480"

  node2:
    image: orientdb:latest
    command: /orientdb/bin/server.sh -Ddistributed=true
    volumes:
      - /orientdb/config2:/opt/orientdb/config
      - /orientdb/databases2:/orientdb/databases
      - /orientdb/backup2:/orientdb/backup
      - ./data2:/orientdb/bin/data
    environment:
      ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pwd1'
      ORIENTDB_NODE_NAME: node2
    depends_on:
      - node1
```

OrientDB configurations setup:

```
val orientGraph = new OrientGraph("url","user","password")
```

How I run the query:

```
val orientTableRows:OrientDynaElementIterable = orientGraph.command(new OCommandSQL("select count(*) as count from Table1"))
      .execute()
```

build.sbt file with OrientDB dependencies:

```
val orientDbVersion = "3.0.4"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-graphdb" % orientDbVersion,
  "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-distributed" % orientDbVersion,
  "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-core" % orientDbVersion,
  "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-client" % orientDbVersion,
  "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-server" % orientDbVersion,
  "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-test-commons" % orientDbVersion,
  "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-tools" % orientDbVersion,
  "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-etl" % orientDbVersion,
  "com.tinkerpop.blueprints" % "blueprints-core" % "2.6.0"
)
```

Comment: You should paginate the query using skip/limit clause. Or increase the heap to be able to fit in ram 5M documents.

Comment: @RobertoFranchini I do need to get al the records. The essence of this task is to measure how much time OrientDB needs to read such an amount of records. So limiting and skipping will not work for me. You mean increasing Java heap?

Comment: Reading again your question, I don't understand where the OOM occurs: on the server or in your application? With such a query, you're trying to load 5M records inside your application. You need a big heap on the application side. On the database side, you are overloading the GC, I guess.

Comment: Yes, the GC is getting overloaded on the database side. I thinkg that OutOfMemory error occurs on the application side

Comment: In the database: Every time loaded records from the storage are sent to the client, the GC has  a lot of work to do to clean up the memory. On the application side: if you don't provide enough heap for 5M records, they will fill it up. You should "consume" the records on the application side: you can do that using the native api rather than the JDBC driver

Comment: Actually, I am using a native Java API. I have updated the question with the database connection setup.

Comment: Ok, which version? how do you perform the query?

Comment: @RobertoFranchini I have added OrientDB version from the dependencies and the code for running a query to the question

Comment: Since you're on 3.0.x, my suggestion is to use the new multimodel API that uses the Java 8 streams: http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/ref/OResultSet.html and consume the stream